# Understanding Matsubara summation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-field-theory

I'm trying to understand matsubara summation.

Let us say I have $f(i\omega) = 1$.
Obviously, the matsubara summation $\sum_{\omega_n} f(i\omega_n)$ diverges.

So, I use a weighing function. Let us say I use ther fermi dirac distribution, $n(z) = \frac{\beta}{1+ e^{\beta z}}$. I also use contour integral.
So, I get $\oint dz f(z)n(z)$ = $\oint dz \frac{\beta}{1+ e^{\beta z}}$.
The poles are at $z = i\omega_n$, with $\omega_n = \frac{2n+1}{\beta}$. So,  I take $z = \epsilon + i\omega$(?) Then the integral becomes $\oint d\omega \frac{\beta}{1+ e^{\beta (\epsilon + i\omega)}}$.
This doesn't seem to help much. Can someone give a pointer or hint how to proceed?  Will some other weighing function help? Or deforming the contour in some way would help?

Comment: Why do you think that the summation over your $f$ should not be divergent?

Comment: It would imply that then any physical quantity which is independent of the matsubara frequency in a thermal bath is divergent.